# How to run SQLCMD script using VB.NET

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net

I am trying to execute SQL query using SQLCMD (SQL Command Prompt) using VB.NET code. I am connecting to the server using Windows Shell script and executing a query and storing the result-set in Excel file. Below is my code which is not working.
What is missing in below code?

```
    Dim Command
    Dim ServerName As String
    Dim DatabaseName As String
    Dim QueryToExceute As String

    ServerName = "IN2175533W1"
    DatabaseName = "C:\FileDirectory\XYZ.mdf"
    QueryToExceute = "Select * from Table_Name"

   Command = """C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE"" " & "-S " & ServerName & " -d " & DatabaseName & " -Q " & QueryToExceute & " -s" & "," & " -o" & "C:\TestQuery.xlsx"

    Dim wsh As Object = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    'Using WScript to execute Stuff
    wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    wsh.Run(Command)
```

I tried process class as well which is not working. Below is my code:

```
    Dim Command
    Dim ServerName As String
    Dim DatabaseName As String
    Dim QueryToExceute As String

    ServerName = "IN2175533W1"
    DatabaseName = "C:\ABC\XYZ.mdf"
    QueryToExceute = "Select * from Quality"


        Dim Process = New Process()
    Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    Process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    Process.StartInfo.FileName = "SQLCMD.EXE"
    Process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-S " & ServerName & "-d" & DatabaseName & "-Q" & QueryToExceute & "-s" & "," & "-o" & "C:\Testing1.xlsx"

    Process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\users\rahul.wankhade\Desktop"
    Process.Start()
    Process.WaitForExit()
```

Comment: SQLCMD is an utility and an application by itself. You should rather use `Process` class

Comment: @Rahul....I tried process class but unable to execute query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I tested, note I changed the server, database and query to match my machine. I'm using string interpolation via VS2015.

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim ServerName As String = "KARENS-PC"
        Dim DatabaseName As String = "C:\Data\NORTHWND.MDF"
        Dim DoubleQuote As String = Chr(34)
        Dim QueryToExceute As String =
            $"{DoubleQuote}SELECT CompanyName,ContactName FROM Customers{DoubleQuote}"
        Dim ExportFileName As String =
            $"{DoubleQuote}C:\Data\MyDataFromSqlServer.csv{DoubleQuote}"

        Dim Process = New Process()
        Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
        Process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        Process.StartInfo.FileName = "SQLCMD.EXE"
        Process.StartInfo.Arguments =
            $"-S {ServerName} -d {DatabaseName} -E -Q {QueryToExceute} -o {ExportFileName} -h-1 -s"","" -w 700"
        Process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Data"
        Process.Start()
        Process.WaitForExit()
        Console.WriteLine("Done")
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub
End Module
```

Conventional way without VS2015

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim ServerName As String = "KARENS-PC"
        Dim DatabaseName As String = "NorthWindAzure"
        Dim DoubleQuote As String = Chr(34)
        Dim QueryToExceute As String =
            DoubleQuote & "SELECT CompanyName,ContactName FROM Customers" & DoubleQuote
        Dim ExportFileName As String =
            DoubleQuote & "C:\Data\MyDataFromSqlServer.csv" & DoubleQuote

        Dim Process = New Process()
        Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
        Process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        Process.StartInfo.FileName = "SQLCMD.EXE"
        Process.StartInfo.Arguments =
            "-S " & ServerName & " -d " & DatabaseName & " -E -Q " &
            QueryToExceute & " -o " & ExportFileName & "  -h-1 -s"","" -w 700"
        Process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Data"

        Process.Start()
        Process.WaitForExit()
        Console.WriteLine("Done")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: ...Thanks a lot..I am using Visual Studio 2012 where String Interpolation does not work....could you rectified your code to work it in visual studio 2012

Comment: This is why it's a good idea to indicate the version :-) I edited my post with a second version for VS2012,

Answer (score 0):

The other way around which I did is below code, read out all code in a string object, parse it with replacing Go to any other symbol and execute the array one by one.

```
Sub ExecuteWithCommand()
    Try
        Dim sFile As FileInfo = New FileInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory.ToString() & "\Script.sql")
        If (sFile.Exists = True) Then
            Dim dbObj = New SqlDataAccess()   
           'your SQL data-access class'
            Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory.ToString() & "\Script.sql")
            Dim scriptArr As String()
            Dim i As Integer
            dbObj.Command.CommandText = objReader.ReadToEnd.Replace("GO", "#")  
            'use any other symbol which you want, keeping in mind, its not used elsewhere in script'
            scriptArr = dbObj.Command.CommandText.Split("#")

            For i = 0 To scriptArr.Length - 1
                dbObj.Command.CommandText = scriptArr.GetValue(i)
                dbObj.Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception            
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
```