# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {10020200-E260-11CF-AE68-00AA004A34D5}

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, exception, .net-4.6.1, sqldmo

I was working with SQL DMO class for some query execution in VB.NET code, and I am getting following error

***{"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {10020200-E260-11CF-AE68-00AA004A34D5} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))."***

I have searched though internet , tried to register the file but no luck.

Below is the code sample:

```
  Dim dbObj = New SqlDataAccess()
  Dim oSQLServer As New SQLDMO.SQLServer
  oSQLServer.Connect(SqlDataAccess.ServerName, SqlDataAccess.UserName, SqlDataAccess.Password)
```

It breaks at third line, the application is running 4.6.1 .Net framework and I am using Windows 10(64bit), VS 2015 Version.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to get it done with a simple query rather then using DMO , SMO libraries:
[Find Solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52778428/1147352)